# How to update a record if a record is above a certain value

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I am using the following code to update visible from cvUpd to 0 when cv.From.Configtext is under or equal to 1200. For this to happen, my query checks, among others, whether cvFrom.ConfigText is equal to r.value, which resides in the OptionRestriction table.

```
    UPDATE cvUpd
SET cvUpd.visible = case when cvFrom.ConfigText <= 1200 then 0 else 1 end
FROM ConfigValue cvUpd
INNER JOIN OptionRestriction r ON cvUpd.ConfigurationID=67151
   AND cvUpd.FeatureID = r.Feature_ID_2
   AND cvUpd.OptionValue= r.OptionValue_2
INNER JOIN ConfigValue cvFrom ON cvFrom.FeatureID =r.Feature_ID_1  
   AND cvFrom.ConfigurationID = cvUpd.ConfigurationID 
   AND cvFrom.OptionValue=r.OptionValue_1 
   AND cvFrom.ConfigText=CONVERT(nvarchar(max), r.value)
   AND (LEN(cvFrom.ConfigText) = 3 or LEN(cvFrom.ConfigText) = 4)
```

Below, the OptionRestriction table can be found and as can be seen OptionValue_2 - 4 should not be visible in case OptionValue_1 - 1 from Feature_ID_1 - 1021 has a value below 1200.

```
+--------------+---------------+-------+--------------+---------------+---------+
| Feature_ID_1 | OptionValue_1 | value | Feature_ID_2 | OptionValue_2 | visible |
+--------------+---------------+-------+--------------+---------------+---------+
|         1021 |             1 |  1200 |          775 |             4 |       0 |
+--------------+---------------+-------+--------------+---------------+---------+
```

This all works fine and thus the correct result is recorded in the ConfigValue table (i.e. visible is updated from 1 to 0, when ConfigText of the corresponding OptionValue_1 and Feature_ID_1 is 1200):

```
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+-------+------------+
| ConfigurationID | FeatureID | OptionValue |   Name   | Visible | Value | ConfigText |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+-------+------------+
|           67151 |       775 |           4 | OName    |       0 |     1 | 03-003     |
|           67151 |      1021 |           1 | Y-waarde |       1 |     0 | 1200       |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+-------+------------+
```

However, when the Confixtext is not 1200, but a random value above 1200, I want visible to change to 1 again, since now visible stays 0, when the ConfigText is changed to a value above 1200 (in the example below to 1300).

```
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+-------+------------+
| ConfigurationID | FeatureID | OptionValue |   Name   | Visible | Value | ConfigText |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+-------+------------+
|           67151 |       775 |           4 | OName    |       0 |     1 | 03-003     |
|           67151 |      1021 |           1 | Y-waarde |       1 |     0 | 1300       |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+-------+------------+
```

What do I need to change in my query to get the following result (visible set to 1 with a ConfixText above 1200)?

```
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+-------+------------+
| ConfigurationID | FeatureID | OptionValue |   Name   | Visible | Value | ConfigText |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+-------+------------+
|           67151 |       775 |           4 | OName    |       1 |     1 | 03-003     |
|           67151 |      1021 |           1 | Y-waarde |       1 |     0 | 1300       |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+-------+------------+
```

### UPDATE

This is the code to create the OptionRestriction table:

```
CREATE TABLE OptionRestriction(
   Feature_ID_1  INTEGER 
  ,Optionvalue_1 INTEGER 
  ,value         INTEGER
  ,Feature_ID_2  INTEGER 
  ,OptionValue_2 INTEGER 
  ,visible       INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO OptionRestriction(Feature_ID_1,Optionvalue_1,value,Feature_ID_2,OptionValue_2,visible) VALUES (1021,1,1200,775,4,0);
```

This is the code to create the ConfigValue table:

```
CREATE TABLE ConfigValue(
   ConfigurationID INTEGER 
  ,FeatureID       INTEGER  
  ,OptionValue     INTEGER  
  ,Name            NVARCHAR(25) 
  ,Visible         INTEGER  
  ,Value           INTEGER  
  ,ConfigText      NVARCHAR(max) 
);
INSERT INTO ConfigValue(ConfigurationID,FeatureID,OptionValue,Name,Visible,Value,ConfigText) VALUES (67151,775,4,N'Y-waarde',0,1,N'03-003');
INSERT INTO ConfigValue(ConfigurationID,FeatureID,OptionValue,Name,Visible,Value,ConfigText) VALUES (67151,1021,1,N'Y-waarde',1,0,N'1300');
```

Comment: How could we know? We need some details to have any chance at helping you here. This is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: How does this even work?  What datatype is config_text?

Comment: I updated my main question. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: So you want to compare a 'freetext' string value to an integer and update the value based on the result of that comparison. You can give a try to `TRY_CONVERT` if you are running SQL Server 2012 or newer.

Comment: Your test data give error: `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__ConfigV__95AA539B2E15E895'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ConfigValue'. The duplicate key value is (67151).`

Comment: Can you try again? I edited my Insert code from configValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is what you want:

```
UPDATE cvUpd
SET cvUpd.visible = case when cvFrom.ConfigText <= r.value then 0 else 1 end
FROM #ConfigValue cvUpd
INNER JOIN #OptionRestriction r ON cvUpd.ConfigurationID=67151
   AND cvUpd.FeatureID = r.Feature_ID_2
   AND cvUpd.OptionValue= r.OptionValue_2
INNER JOIN #ConfigValue cvFrom ON cvFrom.FeatureID =r.Feature_ID_1  
   AND cvFrom.ConfigurationID = cvUpd.ConfigurationID 
   AND cvFrom.OptionValue=r.OptionValue_1 
   AND (LEN(cvFrom.ConfigText) = 3 or LEN(cvFrom.ConfigText) = 4);
```

Comment: Thanks alot Ruslan. Your solution works like a charm! So if I am correct, the convert was not needed and the fixed value had to replaced by r.value in order for the query to understand when to make an option visible and not visible?